# AndEngine astar pathfinding

Tags: android, andengine, path-finding, a-star, tmx

Could anyone give me an example of source code which uses astar pathfinding algorithm with AndEngine on the TMXTiledMap. I am using AndEngine downloaded from https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the official [TMXTiledMapExample](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/TMXTiledMapExample.java), but it doesn't contain A* pathfinding. It can teach you about tiled maps, though.

[Here](http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles1/a-astar-pathfinding-in-tmxtiledmapexample-java-t3949.html) is another example from the forums which does contain it. It isn't really an example, but the pathfinding code provided there works. I don't think there is any real example of A* pathfinding, never seen any tutorial of it (The best way to learn is to read the code yourself. Better take a look at [AStarPathFinder.java](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/util/algorithm/path/astar/AStarPathFinder.java) code).

The important parts for you in the forum post are are (lines):

123: Initializing the `AStarPathFinder`

205 - 213: Converting screen/scene coordinates to map tiles and using the pathfinder.

224: The method `loadPathFound` - using the path returned by the pathfinder to move an entity.

The `MyMap` class in the third post.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually an example in forum uses another version of AndEngine. The classes here have prefix org.anddev and they are differ from the classes in https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine. AStarPathFinder also differs. Do you know any example that exactly uses classes from ttps://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine ? Thanks.

Comment: That's exactly the problem, this example is old - there are no examples with the newer version of AndEngine :( However, the classes didn't change much, only the prefixes of packages. You can take the new package of A* ( org.andengine.util.algorithm.path.astar) and paste it instead of the old one one in the example.

Comment: I could not find new version of AndEngine in github. I saw an examples which use new version as a jar archive. But https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine seems to be active. Do you recommend to use the jar archive? Or is there any place that new version is published?